Dynamic Cesium SVG/Canvas Billboard
I'm using Cesium(denpendencies: "cesium": "1.99")+Vue to build a 3D map project.
I need to build some markers on map and add some animation including opacity and scale changes.
I found that Cesium Billboard can take canvas as an image, so I draw my dynamic canvas and take it as the image. But the billboard does not update.
I tried:
billboard: {
  image: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(() => {
    return this.createPNGCanvas(name);
  }, false),
  ...
}

And also I tried to create my own svg as the image, it doesn't work.
Any sugesstions?
Thank you!

can you share your code as Sandcastle?
